# 3D Quiver Plot Python Glitch: plot covered in blue

Tags: python, plot, vector, 3d

I have been trying to make a 3D velocity vector plot using Quiver, for Azimuth vs Height vs Time.

I have all my data and they are in the correct shapes; however I am getting a glitch of my plot covered in blue (and I have not activated a Python color map yet). I have attached the graph below and my code for creating the graph below that.

[3D Quiver plot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oscb.png)
[Code for Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBcAx.png)

I have tried adjusting the line used to make a 3D quiver plot in lines 160 and 161 of my code,
160   fig = plt.figure()
161   ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

but using different variations such as
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d'), or ax = fig.gca(projection='3d').
This leads to the same image problem.

Is this a problem from my data or the way I set up my plot? What might be the reason for this?